# Got to specific tab on button/link click, ExtJs tabpanel

Tags: extjs

I've a ext js tab panel defined with some tabs.
On the same page I've a menu of hyper links for asking user which tab to open.
I want open the selected tab when the user clicks the link.

Basically when u click on the tab header to open the tab, I want exact same thing to happen on clicking some button/hyperlink.

Seems like a pretty normal thing, but I can't find the solution anywhere!!

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

ues setActiveTab( newItem ) method of tabpanel.You can pass an ID, index or the component itself as newItem.